# How to get elements height of an element dynamically loaded inside an ionicdialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal dialog based on a template in which i load a GoogleMap.

I want the GoogleMap to take the remaining Space below a header and a sub-header included in the template.

-- header -- (height is defined through mediaqueries in css)

-- subheader -- (height is defined through mediaqueries in css)

-- remaining space inside dialog --

This is my controller so far:

```
$scope.creategooglemapsmodal = function() {
    $scope.item.showmap = true;
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/Gmapdialog.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    })
        .then(function (modal) {
            $scope.googlemapsmodal = modal;
            $scope.googlemapsmodal.show()
                .then(function() {
```

// after showing the modal i would like to adjust the mapcontainers height - before i initiate the map, which will call the containers height.

```
                    $scope.showmapinit();
                    $scope.modalhiddenlistener = $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
                        $scope.hidegooglemapsmodal();
                    });             
                });
        });
};
```

What is the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

after initialization of the GoogleMap i call

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

to set Zoom and Center (after placing markers)

And right after that i call:

```
$scope.googlemapsmodal.$el.find('.angular-google-map-container').addClass('expander');
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.expander {
    position:inherit !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

Hope this will help someone